# java - inherited class issue (different methods in subclasses than super)

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass animal and a bunch of inherit classes  ... dog, cat, and pig, etc.

my problem is that all dog cat and pig have their own different parameters.. class "animal" is a introduce parameter object.

so, dog might have getbark.. pig may have getoink..

i have a method that ties "pig" to the class pig.. and a getter that returns a type animal, when i get("pig"); same wit the others..

problem is, if i do Animal animal = get("pig"), and then try to use pig's methods with animal.. ie. animal.oink(), 
i get "The methd is undef for the type animal", because oink is not in animal, it is in pig.

the only way I can think to fix this is to put oink, woof, meow, neigh, and 20 other methods in the superclass.. that would be silly, because dog only needs woof, not oink, meow, neigh, chirp...

I'm sorry for the convoluted example.. It is the only way I could think to explain.. I know that you cannot downcast in Java.,, any solutions?

EDIT:

it was just a simple example.. there is more than just a speak function. for example, a dog has a "comb" function that a pig does not..
could I just have a generic dothings() method in the superclass and have a bunch of methods in the subclass that override that same dothings method multiple times?

Comment: It's called casting... `Pig pig = (Pig) get("pig"); pig.oink();`. Also consider having a `public abstract void makeSound();` in `Animal`.

Comment: Why not have a getSound() method that is overriden in the subclass?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from your decision to give each of these methods a different name. At first glance, it might seem like they all do different things since all animals makes different noises, but it would be a much better idea to just have one method, say, `makeSound`, declared in `Animal` and then implemented in your subclasses. This way, you can call the method from `Animal`. Here's a minimalist example:

```
class Animal
{
    public abstract void makeSound();
}

class Pig extends Animal
{
    public void makeSound()
    {
        System.out.println("oink!")
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    public void makeSound()
    {
        System.out.println("Woof!")
    }
}
```

Allowing for use like this:

```
Animal dog = get("Dog");
dog.makeSound(); //prints "Woof!"
```

This makes sense because regardless of what sound they make, every animal can indeed make a sound, so that behavior should be declared in class `Animal`, and what sound is made can be specified for each animal without adding anything to the class's public methods.

Comment: Instead of makeSound(), how about vocalize()?  Otherwise, it's not clear from which end of the animal the sound should issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to downcast if you test the type of the object with `instanceof` first.

However, it's much better to use polymorphism to your advantage here.  Define an abstract `speak` method in `Animal`, and have all your subclasses implement it, e.g. in `Dog`:

```
public void speak() { System.out.println("woof"); }
```

Then you have the same-named method in all classes, and this will work no matter the actual type of the `animal`:

```
Animal animal = get("pig");  // or any other subtype
animal.speak();  // oink
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. You have to cast your Animal to the correct subclass, this solution is quite dirty and do not use the power of OO programming. For example:

   ```
   if (animal instanceof Pig) {
       ((Pig)animal).oink();
   }
   ```
2. You have to use a generic method for the animal class for example doVerse() and you must override this method in each subclass.

   ```
   class Pig extends Animal {

       public void doVerse() {
          System.out.println("oink");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you'd like to keep specific names for the speak methods (bark, meow, oink, etc), then make sure you're calling them on an instance of that particular animal.

A superclass' main function is to give the subclasses all of the methods universal to them while not having to write the method out for each subclass.

I definitely suggest going with the other answer's polymorphism idea, but as you move on it helps to know specifically what a superclass is for, and how subclasses can have unique methods.

Comment: Use a superclass when you want to _implement_ common behavior that is shared by all of the sub-classes.  If you only want to declare that every `Animal` must be able to `vocalize()`, then it's better for Animal to be an `interface`.